# iOS URLSchemeでメールを送る時、送信ボタンが無効になってしまう

Tags: objective-c, ios8

[MailNow](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mail-now-one-tap-speed-mailer/id825674091?ls=1&mt=8)というアプリを作っているのですが、iOS8.2から突然が不具合が発生しました。
いろいろ試行錯誤してみたのですが、手詰まりになってしまったので助けていただけませんか。

*やりたいこと
TableViewのセルをタップすると、plistに格納されたメールアドレス、タイトル、本文情報を読み込んで、URL scheme経由でiPhoneのメーラーに渡す

*症状
メーラーが起動していないときはうまくいく（送信ボタンが有効になる）が、メーラーを1度起動すると送信ボタンが無効になってしまう。メーラーを終了すれば、送信ボタンが再び有効になる

[症状を動画で撮りました](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCeg0NDJFiw)

URL scheme起動時のコードは下記のとおりです。
問題解決のヒントを頂けたら幸いです。

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSDictionary *ContentDetail = [_defaultList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *email = ContentDetail[@"email"];
    NSString *subject = ContentDetail[@"subject"];
    NSString *message = ContentDetail[@"message"];

    //UTF-8でエンコード
    NSString*encEmail =
    [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString*encSubject =
    [subject stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString*encText =
    [message stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *scheme;
    if (![subject isEqualToString:@""] && ![message isEqualToString:@""]) {
        scheme = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?subject=%@&body=%@",encEmail,encSubject,encText];
    } else if (![subject isEqualToString:@""]) {
        scheme = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?subject=%@",encEmail,encSubject];
    } else if (![message isEqualToString:@""]) {
        scheme = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?body=%@",encEmail,encText];
    } else {
        scheme = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@", encEmail];
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:scheme]];

}
```

Comment: その問題を直接解決するわけではないのですが、 `MFMailComposeViewController` は使わないのでしょうか？

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。なるほど、URL schemeでうまくいかなければ、自前でメールを送るように方向転換したほうがいいかもしれないですね。やってみます！